# Parse YAML response to object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, yaml

Am using swagger-ui, which needs input as in object type.
I was trying `JSON.parse` the YAML response and am getting the below

```
VM9790:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Please suggest the right way to parse the YAML response to an object

Response: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml

Comment: yaml is not json :/ your need a yaml parser

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to parse a YAML file or response is to use a library for that purpose. You can try https://github.com/eemeli/yaml, which seems fairly well maintained at the time of writing this answer.

Install the library in your project:

```
npm install yaml
```

Example usage:

```js
import YAML from 'yaml'
// or
const YAML = require('yaml')


YAML.parse(yamlGoesHere)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use parseDocument.

package.json

```json
"yaml": "^2.1.3"
```

```js
import * as yaml from 'yaml';
/*
 Other code
*/
const document = yaml.parseDocument(yourYamlFile);
console.log(document.get('yourKey'));
```

Comment: Where is `YAML` defined?

Comment: @SebastianThomas at the standards page? https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/